# Is there any better way to work with ajax,php and mysql than this?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Let's suppose that I want to  have the following small code

```
<div id="field"> Some links here with a database call. </div>
```

The problem is that I want to be able to work with ajax on them and call them when the user adds a new link through the appropriate form.

So instead of having this div, I use a function and call it whenever needed using ajax.

```
     <?php  
  function testfield ($id) {  Database call
     ?>
      <div id="field"> <?php The links in here  ?> </div>
      }
   <html>
      <body>
        <?php testfield($_GET['id']); ?> 
     </body>
   </html>
```

So when a user adds a new link, I just call with ajax the function and I'm set.

Is there any other better way to do this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For example you should use JSON and return data into your div.
For AJAX try use jQuery.

PHP code:

```
$linkarray = array();
$linkarray[] = 'link1';
$linkarray[] = 'link2';
$linkarray[] = 'link3';
echo json_encode($linkarray);
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body><div id="linklist"></div></body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
 url:'getlinklist.php',
        dataType:'json',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(data){
            $('#linklist').html('');
            $.each(datamfunction(key,value){
                $('#linklist').append(value+'<br/>');                 
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: How come you suggest json instead of plain text? Also I'm not sure that I understood what exactly you're trying to do. FYI I'm not familiar with json. What more does this approach offers

Comment: JSON is not to hard understand. Try execute my code, and look at firebug when code is handling.

Comment: And one last question, ok I call it on $(document).ready but do I have to copy the ajax part again as a function to call it later ? Because that's what my question was in the first place. I do not want to have the same code twice.

Comment: create function and add allJS code into it. At first code handling on $(document).ready(); and then you may crete a button or link and send AJAX request when user push the button/click the link

Comment: Evgeniy I know that but this div will run once the page has finished loading and then I want it to be updated once the user adds something in the form without having to reload the form. I could easily create a function that contains the .ajax and call it when the document is ready but that would require to be able to pass the $_GET['id'] variable from php to jquery and afaik this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

When user adds a new link, you send data with AJAX to PHP script, which works with database, on success you should refresh DIV with javascript - write new information(you have this already) at the end of DIV, or render all DIV with information, you get from JSON massive, returned with success from PHP script